# Facebook SDK / JQuery Multiple User Search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

this is maybe a stupid question, but is it possible, for an Facebook App to query a user search like in Facebook itself. For example: How to find all Users by there Hometown, school, etc?

All I found was to search for specific users by their username.

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

@Tobi is right in that you cannot achieve this through targeting. Check out this answer:

[Can I use Facebook social graph to show users who graduated from a particular college/university?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259261/can-i-use-facebook-social-graph-to-show-users-who-graduated-from-a-particular-co)

**Old Answer**

Using the endpoint:

```
/search?q={query}&type={type}
```

you can query by location as well.

Check out the **Searching Section** Here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0

And the **Targeting Section** Here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/targeting/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Targeting will not give you a list of users, that's not correct.

Comment: ah ok... so its not possible through an application. Just Facebook itself can filter all user by city or school or whatever. That is sad.. but I already thought so